# Hey I need your help # Python # Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

#Hey I need your help , I create un application with python (and tkinter ), when y run my #code the python Launcher stop my code . It is my Launcher or its my code ? form my it's my code because i thinks is the last v (sorry form my English i am french)

---

#It's My code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.9
# -*-coding:Latin-1 -*

from os import read, write
import _tkinter 
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as font


# -- INPUT HOME PAGE --

#: indiqué votre premier titre de votre home page
input = tk.Entry()
#: indiqué le deuxieme titre de votre home page 
input1 = tk.Entry()
#: Veuillez indiquer la couleur de fond de la home page 
input2 = tk.Entry()
# Voullez vous des Bord rond 'oui' 'non'
input3 = tk.Entry()
#: la couleur du text : 
input4 = tk.Entry()
# -- BackGround Couleur (Home Bar) 
input5 = tk.Entry()
# -- Color (Home Bar)
input6 = tk.Entry()
#: Voulez vous des bord rond sur le cadre des boutton 'oui' 'non'
input7 = tk.Entry()
#: Voullez vous un effets sur les bouton  'aucun' / 'oui1' / 'oui2'
input8 = tk.Entry()


# -- FENETRE --
fenetre = tk.Tk()
fenetre.configure(bg='grey')
fenetre.geometry("5000x1000")


filin = open("apercu.html", "a")
filincss =open("apercu.css", "a")

def titre():
    print("La fonction Titre is activate")

def homePage():
    # getfonction()
    print("function 'getInput' is activate")
    filin.write("\n<DOCTYPE html>\n<head>\n<title>Apercu</title>\n<link rel='stylesheet' href='Apercu.css'>\n<meta charset='utf-8'>\n</head>\n<body>")
    filincss.write("\nbody{\nmargin:0;}\n")
    print("La fonction de la homebar is Avtivate")
    filin.write("\n<div class='homebar''>\n")
    filin.write("\n  <div class='acceuil'><p class='p-home'>Acceuil</p></div>")
    filin.write("\n  <div class='contact'><p class='p-home1'>Contat</p></div>\n</div>")

    filincss.write(".homebar{\nbackground-color:black;\height:150px;\ncolor: orange;\ndisplay: flex;")
    filincss.write("\nborder-bottom-right-radius: 33px;\nborder-bottom-left-radius: 33px;\n}")
    filincss.write("\n.contact{\nposition: relative;\nleft:870px;\nfont-size: 25px;\ntop: 50px;\nborder: solid 3px;\n")

    filincss.write("border-radius:33px;\nwidth: 100px;\nheight: 30px;\n}")
    filincss.write("\n.acceuil{\nposition: relative;\nborder: solid 3px black;\nborder-radius: 33px;\nwidth: 100px;\nheight: 30px;\nleft: 90px;\nfont-size: 25px;\ntop: 50px;\nleft: 30px;}")
    filincss.write("\ncontact:hover,.acceuil:hover{\ntransition-duration: 1s;\ntop: 40px;\n}")

# -- Recuperation des Input Home Page --

def RecupI_HB():
    recup = input.get()
    print(recup)
    recup1 =input2.get()
    print(recup1)
    recup2 = input3.get()
    print(recup2)
    recup3 = input3.get()
    print(recup3)
    recup4 = input3.get()
    print(recup4)
    recup5 = input3.get()
    print(recup5)
    recup6 = input3.get()
    print(recup6)
    recup7 = input3.get()
    print(recup7)

# -- finish --
def finish(filin):
    filin.write("\n</body>\n</DOCTYPE>")
    filin.close()

tekt = tk.Entry()

# -- Boutton Home page --

bouton=tk.Button(fenetre, text="homepage",width=50,command=homePage)

label = tk.Label(fenetre,bg='grey', text="Usine a apercu")

label1  = tk.Label(fenetre, bg='grey',text="Indiquer le nom du clients :")

# -- Sapce -- 
space  = tk.Label(fenetre,bg='grey', text=" ")
space1 = tk.Label(fenetre,bg='grey', text=" ")
space2 = tk.Label(fenetre,bg='grey', text=" ")
space3 = tk.Label(fenetre,bg='black',width=100,height=1, text=" ")
space4 = tk.Label(fenetre,bg='grey', text=" ")
space5 = tk.Label(fenetre,bg='grey', text=" ")
space6 = tk.Label(fenetre,bg='grey', text=" ")
space7 = tk.Label(fenetre,bg='grey', text=" ")

# -- Pack --

label.pack()
space.pack()

label1.pack()
space5.pack()

tekt.pack()

space2.pack()
space6.pack()

space3.pack()
space7.pack()
bouton.pack(padx=50, pady=10)
```

Really I dont say what is the probleme is test the last version of my code and this version dont run also .

Comment: what exactly is the issue? do you get an error? if so provide the entire traceback (starting from word "Traceback") in your question (you can [edit] your question). Or is it something else? Also provide a [mre].

Comment: You need to run tkinter `mainloop()` at the end of your script.  Also better create `Tk()` before creating other widgets.

Comment: Tanks you , really It is juste a mistake from be my .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not running the mainloop. Every tkinter.Tk() window needs a mainloop at the end of the program script. It makes the window run continuously. Also as per @acw1668, tkinter.Tk() should be done before creating any widget. Final code:

```
from os import read, write
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as font


# -- INPUT HOME PAGE --



# -- FENETRE --
fenetre = tk.Tk()
fenetre.configure(bg='grey')
fenetre.state("zoomed")

#: indiqué votre premier titre de votre home page
input = tk.Entry()
#: indiqué le deuxieme titre de votre home page 
input1 = tk.Entry()
#: Veuillez indiquer la couleur de fond de la home page 
input2 = tk.Entry()
# Voullez vous des Bord rond 'oui' 'non'
input3 = tk.Entry()
#: la couleur du text : 
input4 = tk.Entry()
# -- BackGround Couleur (Home Bar) 
input5 = tk.Entry()
# -- Color (Home Bar)
input6 = tk.Entry()
#: Voulez vous des bord rond sur le cadre des boutton 'oui' 'non'
input7 = tk.Entry()
#: Voullez vous un effets sur les bouton  'aucun' / 'oui1' / 'oui2'
input8 = tk.Entry()

filin = open("apercu.html", "a")
filincss =open("apercu.css", "a")

def titre():
    print("La fonction Titre is activate")

def homePage():
    # getfonction()
    print("function 'getInput' is activate")
    filin.write("\n<DOCTYPE html>\n<head>\n<title>Apercu</title>\n<link rel='stylesheet' href='Apercu.css'>\n<meta charset='utf-8'>\n</head>\n<body>")
    filincss.write("\nbody{\nmargin:0;}\n")
    print("La fonction de la homebar is Avtivate")
    filin.write("\n<div class='homebar''>\n")
    filin.write("\n  <div class='acceuil'><p class='p-home'>Acceuil</p></div>")
    filin.write("\n  <div class='contact'><p class='p-home1'>Contat</p></div>\n</div>")

    filincss.write(".homebar{\nbackground-color:black;\height:150px;\ncolor: orange;\ndisplay: flex;")
    filincss.write("\nborder-bottom-right-radius: 33px;\nborder-bottom-left-radius: 33px;\n}")
    filincss.write("\n.contact{\nposition: relative;\nleft:870px;\nfont-size: 25px;\ntop: 50px;\nborder: solid 3px;\n")

    filincss.write("border-radius:33px;\nwidth: 100px;\nheight: 30px;\n}")
    filincss.write("\n.acceuil{\nposition: relative;\nborder: solid 3px black;\nborder-radius: 33px;\nwidth: 100px;\nheight: 30px;\nleft: 90px;\nfont-size: 25px;\ntop: 50px;\nleft: 30px;}")
    filincss.write("\ncontact:hover,.acceuil:hover{\ntransition-duration: 1s;\ntop: 40px;\n}")

# -- Recuperation des Input Home Page --

def RecupI_HB():
    recup = input.get()
    print(recup)
    recup1 =input2.get()
    print(recup1)
    recup2 = input3.get()
    print(recup2)
    recup3 = input3.get()
    print(recup3)
    recup4 = input3.get()
    print(recup4)
    recup5 = input3.get()
    print(recup5)
    recup6 = input3.get()
    print(recup6)
    recup7 = input3.get()
    print(recup7)

# -- finish --
def finish(filin):
    filin.write("\n</body>\n</DOCTYPE>")
    filin.close()

tekt = tk.Entry()

# -- Boutton Home page --

bouton=tk.Button(fenetre, text="homepage",width=50,command=homePage)

label = tk.Label(fenetre,bg='grey', text="Usine a apercu")

label1  = tk.Label(fenetre, bg='grey',text="Indiquer le nom du clients :")

# -- Sapce -- 
space  = tk.Label(fenetre,bg='grey', text=" ")
space1 = tk.Label(fenetre,bg='grey', text=" ")
space2 = tk.Label(fenetre,bg='grey', text=" ")
space3 = tk.Label(fenetre,bg='black',width=100,height=1, text=" ")
space4 = tk.Label(fenetre,bg='grey', text=" ")
space5 = tk.Label(fenetre,bg='grey', text=" ")
space6 = tk.Label(fenetre,bg='grey', text=" ")
space7 = tk.Label(fenetre,bg='grey', text=" ")

# -- Pack --

label.pack()
space.pack()

label1.pack()
space5.pack()

tekt.pack()

space2.pack()
space6.pack()

space3.pack()
space7.pack()
bouton.pack(padx=50, pady=10)

fenetre.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add this at the end:

```
fenetre.mainloop()
```

In addition, you don't need the `import _tkinter`

Comment: Tanks you , really It is juste a mistake from be my .